# Нужно ли обособление определения/обстоятельства?

Tags: пунктуация, определения, обстоятельство

*В плену амбиций своих(,) как жалок ты в масштабах Вселенной!*

Можно ли считать "в плену амбиций своих" определением? Если можно, то, насколько я понимаю, его нужно обособить как имеющее добавочное обстоятельственное значение ("будучи в плену амбиций своих...") либо вовсе как относящееся к личному местоимению.

С другой стороны, это можно принять за обстоятельство (где? — "в плену амбиций своих"), и тогда запятая вроде как не требуется.

Comment: Если _Вселенная_ употреблена как астрономический термин, при этом в предложении должна быть полностью речь о космосе, то пишем с большой буквы. Здесь вряд ли так, так что _вселенная_ смело пишите со строчной.